# Plotly bars stacked on top of each other

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I've been working on data visualization with plotly using a bar chart, though I came accross an issue which I wasn't able to find any assistance elsewhere. Here is an image of what I've got so far:
[Comparing laptops according to their price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skSXP.png)

This is the code written which produces the chart:

```
df = pd.read_csv('laptops.csv')

        fig_a = px.bar(df, y='Price', x='Laptops', title='Comparing the cost of each laptop.')
        fig_a.update_layout(
            height=800,
            width=800,
            margin=dict(
                l=50,
                r=50,
                b=100,
                t=100,
                pad=4,
            ),
            xaxis_categoryorder='total descending',
            barmode='relative'
        )

        fig_a.write_image('plots/laptops1.png')
```

So, the issue is that some of the laptop names are the same, with the only difference being their price. Plotly automatically stacks those on top of each other, which is something I don't want. Is there a way to show each bar separately even with the x-axis values (laptops) being equal? I tried using barmode and give different values like 'group' or 'relative', but there weren't any changes whatsoever.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would adding `barmode='group'` to the `px.bar()` do anything vs having it as part of update_layout? Alternatively, you could iterate over your `df['Laptops'].unique()` and create a `df_filt = df[df['Laptops'] == laptop]` (I hope this makes sense: `for laptop in df['Laptops'].unique()`) and then create a list of figures, then plot this list. Though if you want to separate each laptop entry separately despite there being duplicates of this name then you need to have a way of making them unique. Plotly/anyone/anything cannot separate items if there is no means to.

Comment: @Paul Wilson Changing the barmode directly in the px.bar() didn't show any changes, and the iteration which was suggested neither did the work I want. Originally, the laptop names are unique since the scraper I made collects them from a e-shop website, they go on as: 'Huawei MateBook D 15 (R5-3500U/8GB/256GB/FHD/W10) Mystic Silver' which is changed to 'Huawei MateBook D 15 Mystic Silver' using a ReGex. The issue is that keeping the longer string works, but on the contrary the characters go out of proportion when the plot is saved as an image. And when I shorten the names, a new issue comes by.

Comment: And even with changing the width and height to fit them all, the image saved is too large.

Comment: can you provide a sample of the dataset in the csv file?

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding an index infront of every string as they're being inserted into the list. So, now the plots display things how I want. Thanks for your time.